# Sqlite database doesn't use existing index

Tags: database, indexing, sqlite

I created indexes on 3 columns, but searching is still very slow. It appears index is not used at all.

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE users(username, address, date_signup);
CREATE INDEX usersindex on users (username, address, date_signup);
sqlite> explain query plan select * from users where username = 'johndoe';
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE users
sqlite>
```

How do I fix this?

Edit: sqlite version that I'm using is `SQLite version 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24`

Comment: Since both Shawn and I cannot reproduce your results, you need to give more info, in particular, which version of sqlite3 you are using.

Comment: Updated the question to indicate I'm using `SQLite version 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement:

```
select * from users where username = 'johndoe'
```

would run faster for sure if an index existed for the column `username` but **there isn't one**. 
The index you created:

```
CREATE INDEX usersindex on users (username, address, date_signup)
```

is **not** an index for `username` but for all 3 columns `username, address, date_signup`.  
 Of course I don't know if this was your intention.  
If you run `SELECT` statements including `WHERE` or `JOIN` clauses referring to these 3 columns together you should see an improvement.

Comment: Er, no. Since `username` by itself is a prefix of the columns used in that index, it can use that index for that query. See https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#_multi_column_indices

Comment: I hope what you **mean** is: that in situations where a triple index on `(username, address, date_signup)` is **really needed**, there is no need for another index on `(username)`.<br/> I hope what you **don't mean** is: that in situations where a triple index on `(username, address, date_signup)` is **not really needed**, then an index on `(username)` only would not do better as the triple one.

Comment: I **mean** that OP's index should be getting used for queries that only look at `username`, or only `username` and `address`, or `username` and `address` and `date_signup` (But *not* `address` and `date_signup` without `username`). That's how multi-column indexes work. And, indeed, that index **is** being used when other people try OP's example, including testing with a very old sqlite version. So OP has something else going on that they're not mentioning. The last sentence of your answer implies that the index shouldn't be used for the sample query, which is incorrect.

Comment: My last sentence says: "if I need to search or join with the `username` column I will **not** create a triple index even if it would as efficiently  as the triple one (I don't believe there is any chance of it)". Just aside: I did not downovote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to replicate.

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.25.3 2018-11-05 20:37:38
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE users(username, address, date_signup);
sqlite> CREATE INDEX usersindex on users (username, address, date_signup);
sqlite> explain query plan select * from users where username = 'johndoe';
QUERY PLAN
`--SEARCH TABLE users USING COVERING INDEX usersindex (username=?)
sqlite>
```

As you can see, it's using the index as expected. From your EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN format, you're using an older version... just how old? It's possible changes and fixes to the query planner have been made since that one that might impact the results. You can go through the [change log](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) to see.

(The oldest version of the sqlite3 shell I have installed is 3.22, and that also uses the index.)

Comment: I tried it on sqlite3 3.8.8.3 and got the same result (the index is used).

Comment: @varro Thanks for testing an old version. Given that, I think OP has to be leaving something important out of their question. Not sure what, though.

Comment: It's weird but I'm unable to replicate given your example on a newly created (empty) database as well. Query planner shows the index will be used. Although the real database where it doesn't work has absolutely the same schema.